# Shortest route from one source to multiple destinations (simpler variation of the "Traveling salesman")

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to implement a solution for the following problem:

Given a source vertex and a list of destination vertices in a directed acyclic graph, compute the list of paths that would visit all the vertices in an optimal way (minimum number of distinct vertices visited), given there's no "travel cost" in going back to the source vertex, or to a previously visited vertex.

The resulting paths must be given in an order such as the first vertex of each path must be the source vertex or a vertex visited before in a previous path. So a path can restart from any visited vertex, or from the source vertex if nothing was visited before.

(Not a homework assignment, I just wrote the problem definition to make the question clearer. The problem I'm trying to solve is dynamically joining tables on a database, given I know the tables relationship graph, and I'll be joining one table to many others. In this simplification of my actual problem, the source is in the "root" of the graph.)

So given this graph:

```
  source = 1
         /   \
        2     3
        |     |
dest1 = 4     /
         \   /
   dest2 = 5
```

So children are below parents. The expected result, given source `1` and destinations `4` and `5`, would be:

```
Path 1 = 1 -> 2 -> 4
Path 2 = 4 -> 5
```

Note that a naive implementation that would get the individual shortest paths from source to each destination would result in a non-optimal solution is this case:

```
Path 1 = 1 -> 2 -> 4
Path 2 = 1 -> 3 -> 5
```

Making an "extra" visit to the vertex `3`.

I've managed to solve the first requirement, namely computing the list of optimal paths. **BUT** I could not manage to guarantee the required result order for all different permutations of given destinations.

So in some cases I would compute something like:

```
Path 1 = 4 -> 5
Path 2 = 1 -> 2 -> 4
```

This is my code so far:

```
public class ShortestPath {

  public ShortestPath(Vertex source) {
    // build shortest path from source to all children
  }

  public boolean hasPathTo(Vertex dest) {
    // returns true if there's a path to dest, false otherwise
  }

  public int distTo(Vertex dest) {
    // returns the distance to dest, or Integer.MAX_VALUE if there's no path
    // to dest
  }

  public Deque<Vertex> to(Vertex dest) {
    // returns path to dest, including source as the first element in the
    // path, or throws IllegalArgumentException if there's no path to dest
  }

  public Collection<Deque<Vertex>> to(List<Vertex> destinations) {
    Map<Vertex, Deque<Vertex>> destToPath = new HashMap<>();
    for (Vertex dest : destinations) {
      Deque<Vertex> path = to(dest);
      for (Map.Entry<Vertex, Deque<Vertex>> entry : destToPath.entrySet()) {
        Vertex source2 = entry.getKey();
        Deque<Vertex> path2 = entry.getValue();
        if (source2.shortestPath().distTo(dest) < path.size() - 1) {
          // If there's a shorter path from source2 to dest
          path = source2.shortestPath().to(dest);
        } else if (dest.shortestPath().distTo(source2) < path2.size() - 1) {
          // If there's a shorter path from dest to source2
          entry.setValue(dest.shortestPath().to(source2));
        }
      }
      destToPath.put(dest, path);
    }
    return destToPath.values();
  }
}
```

I've tried sorting the destinations in hierarchical order, but that did not solve the result order. I've also tried to create a `Comparator` that would sort the result, but I could not figure out a proper algorithm for it.

Also, I've tried to improve the code above so it would use a separate `List` structure and do `add(i, path)` to add the path to specific indexes in the `List`, but what I've done also failed for some inputs used in my tests.

Is there an algorithm already written to solve this specific problem? If not, any ideia on an approach that would guarantee the result order specified above?

**EDIT:** Sorting the result is not so straightforward. For a little bit more complex result like:

```
Path 1 = 1 -> 2 
Path 2 = 2 -> 4
Path 3 = 4 -> 5
```

How would the `Comparator` compute `int compare(Deque<Vertex> o1, Deque<Vertex> o2)` given Path 1 and Path 3 above?

Comment: Isn't a comparator for sorting the paths super easy? Just compare the first elements.

Comment: This is a question that covers a software algorithm, so should be [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Michael, I've updated my question. Good point.

Comment: If you have to visit node 1, 2, 3, and 4, is it okay to start from node 2 to get to node 4, or must you start from 1 (the beginning is special) or 3 ( where left off?)  In general, can you restart from any visited node?

Comment: @RobNeuhaus, yes, we can restart from any visited node? (Or from the source node, if nothing was visited before).

Comment: Then I think this is exactly the steiner tree problem with some post-processing to figure out the order of the paths.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem  .  Bad news, this is NP-complete.

Comment: @RobNeuhaus, thanks for the reference! I just didn't figure out how would a Steiner tree solve the paths orders requirement I have. Looks like I'm already connecting the "lines" in a "Steiner tree" way with my code above.

Comment: Probably additional comments aren't the best format for this conversation.  I am happy to continue this over email (rrenaud@gmail.com or other messaging medium of your choice).  Recovering the order from the tree is easy, finding the tree is hard.  If you had the steiner tree, you could do iterative greedy shortest paths computations starting at your desired node and stop once you hit an already visited node.  The bigger problem is that computing that steiner tree is going to be hard to do quickly and exactly for all inputs.